# Deleting files by checking file size in bash

Tags: bash, size, delete

I have two directories with files, one is the "source", the other
"destination". I would like to have a script that checks file
in "source". If file name and size matches that at "destination",
the file at "source" is deleted. Preferably using bash.

Is it good enough to use blocksize for comparisons?

Have written the following, but the files are not being printed.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $*; do
    echo "$file"
    # get size of regular files
    [ -f "$file" ] && ls -l "$file"
done
```

Comment: You care only about the size, not the content?

Comment: match filename and size.  Thusly I will read the files in the destination directory and match their existence in the source, finally deleting the file at source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help, with the caveat that this does *not* support file/directory names that include spaces.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

readonly source_dir="${1}"
readonly destination_dir="${2}"

if [[ "${source_dir}" = "" ]] || [[ "${destination_dir}" = "" ]]; then
    echo 1>&2 "usage ${0} <source_dir> <destination_dir>"
    exit 1
fi

for source_file in $(cd "${source_dir}"; find . -type f); do
    full_source="$(cd "${source_dir}" && readlink -f "${source_file}")"

    if [[ -f "${destination_dir}/${source_file}" ]]; then
        full_destination="$(cd "${destination_dir}" && readlink -f "${source_file}")"

        source_size="$(stat --printf="%s" "${full_source}")"
        destination_size="$(stat --printf="%s" "${full_destination}")"

        if [[ "${source_size}" = "${destination_size}" ]]; then
            rm -i "${full_source}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

The script takes two parameters, the name of the source directory and the name of the destination directory.

It then loops over the files in the given source directory.  If a file with the same name exists in the given destination directory, then it uses `stat` to get the sizes of the two files.  If the sizes match, then it removes the source file.

Note that I include the `-i` (interactive) option to `rm` so that it prompts before removing the file.  This will enable you to verify that it's doing the right thing before it blindly removes anything you might care about.  If you find it does what you want and feel comfortable with it, you might choose to remove the `-i`.

Comment: I will check it out.  I see you use stat.  Thank you

Comment: Very neat.  I like it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, this is useful, upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept an alternate to bash...

```
jdupes --delete --paramorder --recurse destination source
```

This will find matching file (name and content) and delete the duplicates. The `--paramorder` and the order of the arguments `destination source` is important if you want to use the `--noprompt` option since it will preserve the first duplicate in the list when deleting and you wanted to preserve the files in the destination.

See [jdupes man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/jdupes/jdupes.1.en.html)